# Is posible install MariaDB v.10 on Qnap QTS 4.2?

Tags: mariadb, qnap

I need to have MariaDB v.10 on my Qnap NAS QTS 4.2, but I don't know how do it.

Is it possible ? How do it ?

Comment: https://www.qnap.com/en/app_center/index.php?kw=db#content_top link shows QMariaDB available as an app. Perhaps asking a question on https://forum.qnap.com/ might generate better results.

Comment: yes, on <a href="https://forum.qnap.net.pl/temat/czy-jest-dostepna-mariadb-10-na-qnap.18067/#post-108773" title="Qnap Club Poland"> I found someone who positive answered, and showed how it do. It is possible using Container Station.

Comment: Excellent. Feel free to answer your own question and mark it as answered so as to put closure to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. 
Installing and using MariaDB on Qnap (QTS 4.2) is possible with Container Station (Docker) https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/ .